# What is the total storage for this server? Is it an external or internal?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hardware-rec

Please help to understand!!!!

```
 H/W path Device Class Description ======================================================== 
system Computer - /0 bus Motherboard /0/0

 - memory 141GiB System memory /0/1

 - processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz /0/2 - processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz /0/100
 - bridge 5520 I/O Hub to ESI Port /0/100/1
 - bridge 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 /0/100/1/0
 - scsi0 storage Smart Array G6 controllers /0/100/1/0/3.0.0
 - generic P410i /0/100/1/0/0.0.0 /dev/sda disk 299GB
 - LOGICAL VOLUME /0/100/1/0/0.0.0/1 /dev/sda1 volume 268GiB
 - EXT3 volume /0/100/1/0/0.0.0/2 /dev/sda2 volume 11GiB
 - Extended partition /0/100/1/0/0.0.0/2/5 /dev/sda5 volume 11GiB - Linux swap / Solaris partition /0/100/1/0/0.0.1 /dev/sdb disk - 200GB LOGICAL VOLUME /0/100/1/0/0.0.1/1 /dev/sdb1 volume
 - 186GiB Linux filesystem partition /0/100/2
 - bridge 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 2 /0/100/3
 - bridge 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 /0/100/4
 - bridge 5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 4 /0/100/5
 - bridge 5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 5 /0/100/6
 - bridge 5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 6 /0/100/7
 - bridge 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 /0/100/7/0
 - eth0 network NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
 - /0/100/7/0.1 eth1 network NetXtreme II BCM5709
 - Gigabit Ethernet /0/100/8 bridge
 - 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 8 /0/100/8/0
 - eth2 network NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
 - /0/100/8/0.1 eth3 network NetXtreme II BCM5709
 - Gigabit Ethernet /0/100/9 bridge
 - 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 9 /0/100/a
 - bridge 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 10
 - /0/100/14 generic 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O
 - Hub System Management Registers /0/100/14.1
 - generic 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers - /0/100/14.2 generic 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O
 - Hub Control Status and RAS Registers /0/100/1c
 - bridge 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1 /0/100/1c.4 - bridge 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
 - /0/100/1c.4/0 generic Integrated Lights-Out
 - Standard Slave Instrumentation & System Support /0/100/1c.4/0.2
 - generic Integrated Lights-Out Standard Management Processor
 - Support and Messaging /0/100/1c.4/0.4 bus
 - Integrated Lights-Out Standard Virtual USB Controller /0/100/1d
 - bus 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 /0/100/1d.1 - bus 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 /0/100/1d.2 - bus 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 /0/100/1d.3 - bus 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 /0/100/1d.7 - bus 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 /0/100/1e
 - bridge 82801 PCI Bridge /0/100/1e/3 display - ES1000 /0/100/1f bridge 82801JIB (ICH10) - LPC Interface Controller /0/100/1f.2 storage
 - 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1 /0/101
 - bridge Intel Corporation /0/102 bridge - Intel Corporation /0/103 bridge Intel - Corporation /0/104 bridge Intel
 - Corporation /0/105 bridge
 - 7500/5520/5500/X58 Physical Layer Port 0 /0/106
 - bridge 7500/5520/5500 Physical Layer Port 1 /0/107
 - bridge Intel Corporation /0/108 bridge - Intel Corporation /0/109 bridge Intel - Corporation /0/10a bridge Intel
 - Corporation /0/10b bridge Intel
 - Corporation /0/10c bridge Intel
 - Corporation /0/10d bridge Xeon 5600
 - Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers /0/10e
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture System Address
 - Decoder /0/10f bridge Xeon 5600 Series - QPI Link 0 /0/110 bridge Xeon 5600
 - Series QPI Physical 0 /0/111 bridge
 - Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 0 /0/112
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 1 /0/113
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 1 /0/114
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 1 /0/115
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Registers
 - /0/116 bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder /0/117
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller RAS
 - Registers /0/118 bridge Xeon 5600
 - Series Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers /0/119
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0
 - Control /0/11a bridge Xeon 5600 Series - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address /0/11b
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0
 - Rank /0/11c bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control /0/11d
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1
 - Control /0/11e bridge Xeon 5600 Series - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address /0/11f
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1
 - Rank /0/120 bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control /0/121
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2
 - Control /0/122 bridge Xeon 5600 Series - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address /0/123
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2
 - Rank /0/124 bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control /0/125
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core
 - Registers /0/126 bridge Xeon 5600
 - Series QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder /0/127
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 0 /0/128
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 0 /0/129
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 0 /0/12a
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 1 /0/12b
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 1 /0/12c
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 1 /0/12d
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Registers
 - /0/12e bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder /0/12f
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller RAS
 - Registers /0/130 bridge Xeon 5600
 - Series Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers /0/131
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0
 - Control /0/132 bridge Xeon 5600 Series - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address /0/133
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0
 - Rank /0/134 bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control /0/135
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1
 - Control /0/136 bridge Xeon 5600 Series - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address /0/137
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1
 - Rank /0/138 bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control /0/139
 - bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2
 - Control /0/13a bridge Xeon 5600 Series - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address /0/13b
-bridge Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2
 - Rank /0/13c bridge Xeon 5600 Series
 - Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control /0/3
 - scsi1 storage /0/3/0.0.0 /dev/cdrom disk
 - DVD A DS8A5LH /0/4 scsi3 storage
 - /0/4/0.0.0 /dev/sdc disk 15GB SCSI Disk
 - /0/4/0.0.0/1 /dev/sdc1 volume 14GiB Windows FAT volume
```

Comment: At the moment, your question is difficult to read. Please [edit] your question to adjust your formatting so we can comfortably read your details, and please remove information that isn't related to the matter at hand.

Comment: Can you filter out all the information that isn't a storage device?  If you can do that, in order to make your question concise, your question is basically unreadable

Answer (score 5):

> - generic P410i /0/100/1/0/0.0.0 /dev/sda disk 299GB
> - /dev/sdb disk - 200GB
> - /dev/sdc disk 15GB SCSI Disk

Add it up... 299 + 200 + 15 = 514 GB. Across three separate (apparently) storage devices.

From the info you've provided, it's impossible to know:

- Where the disks are located
- What type of disks they are (SSD, HDD, USB stick, etc.)

Comment: At least one is a SCSI disk....the other two likely SATA given other information ( I.e CPU) since (IDE) has been discontinued from new hardware for several years now

Comment: cept sata means scsi ata.... s-ata...

Comment: @djsmiley2k SATA means Serial ATA.